# PhoneApplicationService.State vs PhoneApplicationPage.State

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the difference between `PhoneApplicationService.State` and `PhoneApplicationPage.State`?

To me it seems they serve the same purpose, are there specific situations where I would prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PhoneApplicationService.State` should be used for any application level details you wish to store, while `PhoneApplicationPage.State` is for page level details.

A unique PAP.State is created for each page in teh application and you should use this whenever possible. There is a single PAS instance for the entire app and you should only use this for anything running in the context of the application as a whole (i.e. not within a page).

For more see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state(VS.92).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707603(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: thanks matt, your answer in the second paragraph was what i was looking for. I suspected this behavior, but couldnt find it in the doc.

Answer (score 5):

`PhoneApplicationPage.State` can only be accessed during or after the **OnNavigatedTo** override or during or before the **OnNavigatedFrom** override. It is also limited to 2MB of data. For these reasons, it is used for storing transient data releated to tombstoning.

`PhoneApplicationService.State` is used to persist data between application invocations.

If you want to learn more about tombstoning, I'd highly recommend Jeff Prosise's series on [Real-World Tombstoning](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/04/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-1.aspx).